# How to add toggling of the disabled state of an input via double click from inside a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was trying the following but the input isn't being disabled although the scope variable properly updates:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <input type="text" my-input />
    </div>
</body>
```

and

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {})
.directive('myInput', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.disabled = false;
            if (!('disabled' in attrs)) {
                element.attr('ng-disabled', 'disabled');                       
            }
            element.bind('dblclick', function() {
                scope.disabled = !scope.disabled;
                alert(scope.disabled);
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

See: http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:rfqcl9AHEoJZEEJxyNn2?p=preview

Comment: scope.disabled = false; make it to true

Comment: your plunker doesn't contain a directive

Comment: @stanze that is just the initialization, the toggling happens in `scope.disabled = !scope.disabled;`

Comment: @zorza yes it does, see `<input type="text" my-input />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some change in your code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" my-input ng-disabled="disabled" />
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {})
.directive('myInput', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.disabled = false;
            element.bind('dblclick', function() {
                scope.disabled = !scope.disabled;
                alert(scope.disabled);
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

See: http://plnkr.co/edit/g0qtbFJb1V4OxcXNRTVf?p=preview

**EDIT (add the ng-disabled from inside the directive):**

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" my-input/>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {})
.directive('myInput', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.disabled = false;
            element.attr('ng-disabled', 'disabled'); 
            element.removeAttr('my-input'); 
            $compile(element)(scope);
            element.bind('dblclick', function() {
                scope.disabled = !scope.disabled;
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

See: http://plnkr.co/edit/g0qtbFJb1V4OxcXNRTVf?p=preview

Comment: Thanks very much, this does disable the input. But for one thing I really want to add the `ng-disabled` from **inside** the directive. And this code doesn't enable it again on double click (my original doesn't either I guess) Any idea why?

Comment: There is no event (hover, click, double click, ...) was fired after disabling the input. So, you cannot enable the disable input by double click on it.

Comment: Fair enough, there are workarounds for that. But how would I add the `ng-disabled` from inside the directive?

Comment: Aah, thanks man that worked! :) so the `element.removeAttr('my-input'); ` is elementary

Comment: element.removeAttr('my-input') helps to avoid infinity loop when compiling in the next line  $compile(element)(scope).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73425/discussion-between-tai-huynh-and-user511287).