# Angular dynamically adding directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slimscroll

I want to dynamically use angular-slimscroll in my webpage. The directive looks something like this:

```
<div id="scroll" slimscroll="{slimscrollOption: value}">
    Scroll Content
</div>
```

How can I dynamically add `slimscroll="{slimscrollOption: value}"` into `#scroll` div and have it functioning with angular-slimscroll?

Comment: Not sure if this is possible with slimscroll, but you could enable/disable it with a variable and have the slimscroll attribute permanently embedded in the `div`.

Comment: @orange I don't find the variable to enable/disable it in slimscroll. But is it possible to dynamically add directive and have it executed? If that can be done, it may works as what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a directive, some thing like that:

**JS**

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {})
.directive('myScroll', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            element.attr('slimscroll', '{slimscrollOption: value}'); 
            element.removeAttr('my-scroll'); 
            $compile(element)(scope);

        }
    };
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="scroll" my-scroll>
    Scroll Content
</div>
```

The key is you need to $compile the element again to dynamically add angular-slimscroll. And removing attribute 'my-scroll' to advoid infinity loop while compiling.

You can see my answer here also (it is the same as your case, I think): [How to add toggling of the disabled state of an input via double click from inside a directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164542/how-to-add-toggling-of-the-disabled-state-of-an-input-via-double-click-from-insi/29164845#29164845)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It works!!!! But one question here. What is the purpose of that `scope: true`? I remove it, it still works.

Comment: Scope : False ( Directive uses its parent scope ). Scope : True ( Directive gets a new scope ). Scope : { } ( Directive gets a new isolated scope ). You could find more detail here: http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/